# Rails not processing JSON params in get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec

When you `post` JSON as parameters, Rails normally does all the parsing for you if you specify `Content-type: application/json` in the header.

### Is this the same for `get` requests?

In the following rspec request spec, the params sent as JSON are **not being parsed despite the correct header.** Why?

```
@headers = { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }
get cases_path(query_params), params: params.to_json, headers: @headers
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a controller behavior or it's because of RSpec -- since it's not common to make a GET with a JSON in the body request. I suggest you to make a test just to make sure it's not the RSpec mocking something different than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do in our app:

```
@headers = { "ACCEPT" => "application/json" }
get cases_path(query_params), { my_param: param_value }, @headers
```

I.e. just pass the params as a hash. Any luck?